# Django Redirect by Name - No Reverse Match Error

Tags: python, django, redirect, parameter-passing

My django project name is 'exercises' and the app name is 'practice'. This basic application allows a user can navigate to different pages with a button click. The reference to each page uses the following href:

```py
{% url 'practice:redirector' project.pk %}
```

Where practice:redirector points to my app (practice) url path named redirector. It is parameterized with the primary key of the page which I am trying to redirect to.  See below

```py
    from django.urls import path
    
    from practice import views
    
    app_name = "practice"
    urlpatterns = [
        path('', views.all_sites, name="all_sites"),
    
        path('<int:pk>', views.redirector, name='redirector'),
    
        path('clickToAddItems', views.clickToAddItems, name='clickToAddItems'),
        path('displayEvens', views.displayEvens, name='displayEvens'),
        path('displayMousePosition', views.displayMousePosition, name='displayMousePosition'),
        path('luckySevens', views.luckySevens, name='luckySevens'),
    ]
```

This url points to the views within practice. There, I have a view set up for each page that corresponds to the name that the page will display. I also have a re director view that uses the pk passed in the url to pull the relevant page from my database and use the name as the argument in the redirect() shortcut:

```py
    from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
    from practice.models import Project
    app_name = "practice"
    # Create your views here.
    
    
    # Main list of javascript sites
    def all_sites(request):
    # query my project model to return all site objects
        projects = Project.objects.all()
    # return a rendered template with the site information passed into it
        return render(request, 'practice/all_sites.html', {'projects':projects})
    
    def clickToAddItems(request):
        return render(request, 'practice/clickToAddItems')
    
    def displayEvens(request):
        return render(request, 'practice/displayEvens')
    
    def displayMousePosition(request):
        return render(request, 'practice/displayMousePosition')
    
    def luckySevens(request):
        return render(request, 'practice/luckySevens')
    
    def redirector(request, pk):
        project = Project.objects.get(pk=pk)
        site_name=project.title
        return redirect(site_name, permanent=True)
```

I am expecting django to use the redirector view to redirect depending on the provided name. Using the debugger, I can see that the database is correctly queried and the correct name is passed to the redirect with each url:

```py
 C:\Users\User\my_repository\my_repository\Dev\small-projects\practice\views.py, line 29, in redirector
    def luckySevens(request):
        return render(request, 'practice/luckySevens')
    def redirector(request, pk):
        project = Project.objects.get(pk=pk)
        site_name=project.title

        return redirect(site_name, permanent=True) 
    
    # Local vars:
        #(These are the local variables tracked by the debugger, not project code)
    pk   = 1
    project = <Project: Project object (1)>
    request = <WSGIRequest: GET '/practice/1'>
    site_name = 'clickToAddItems'
```

However, I get a NoReverseMatch error because django is using the project url file instead of my application url file to find the corresponding view.

```py
    C:\Users\User\my_repository\my_repository\Dev\small-projects\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\base.py, line 88, in reverse
                    else:
                        raise NoReverseMatch("%s is not a registered namespace" % key)
            if ns_pattern:
                resolver = get_ns_resolver(
                    ns_pattern, resolver, tuple(ns_converters.items())
                )
        return resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs) …
    reverse_lazy = lazy(reverse, str)
    def clear_url_caches():
       
     # Local vars:
    #(These are the local variables tracked by the debugger, not project code)
    args = []
    current_app = None
    current_path = None
    kwargs = {}
    ns_converters = {}
    ns_pattern = ''
    path = []
    prefix = '/'
    resolved_path = []
    resolver = <URLResolver 'exercises.urls' (None:None) '^/'>
    urlconf = 'exercises.url'
    view = 'clickToAddItems'
    viewname = 'clickToAddItems'
```

I need the resolver to look at 'practice.urls' instead of 'exercises.urls'. How can I do this? I have tried parameterizing urlconf=practice.urls within the redirect shortcut of the redirector view, but that does not work. Any and all feed back is very much appreciated! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to redirect to

```
site_name = 'clickToAddItems'
```

as in your debug example, you should name the app:

```
site_name = 'practice:clickToAddItems'
```